# makefile unexpectedly removes target

Tags: makefile

A minimal example:

```
%.txt: foo.log
    # pass

%.log:
    # pass
```

Run:

```
$ make a.txt --dry-run
# pass
# pass
rm foo.log
```

Why is the last action `rm foo.log`?
How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 30):

By default, GNU make removes intermediate files.  Since %.txt depends on %.log, make wants to remove the .log file.  To prevent that behavior you mark them as precious with .PRECIOUS or .SECONDARY.

```
.PRECIOUS: foo.log
```

Also, you can make it so that no intermediate files are ever removed by using .SECONDARY with no dependencies.

```
.SECONDARY:
```

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-preserving-with-_002eSECONDARY) section of the GNU make manual.

Answer (score 7):

You are making `a.txt` by means of a chain of *implicit rules* (in this case implicit rules which you defined yourself). So Make considers `foo.log` an [intermediate file](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules), and deletes it when it has served its purpose. You can override this behavior by declaring `foo.log` a SECONDARY target:

```
.SECONDARY: foo.log
```

Comment: .SECONDARY: %.log # doesnt work, what should I do to make the rule general?

Comment: If you want all intermediates to remain, just declare a target of .SECONDARY:   with no dependencies.  Alternatively, you can use the wildcard with .PRECIOUS.  i.e. .PRECIOUS: %.log

Comment: I know but that's what the manual says.  If you've ever read the manual then you know that this is not the most surprising inconsistency.