# makefile intermediate rule-specific

Tags: makefile

A makefile generates a file from another via an intermediate and automatically deletes the intermediate file:

```
.INTERMEDIATE $(B_FILES)

%.b : %.a
    a_to_b $<

%.c : %.b
    b_to_c $<

all: $(A_FILES)
```

The above is a simplified example - it produces a .c file and deletes the intermediate .b file. It's possible to produce and keep the intermediate .b file if made specifically:

```
$ make my_file.b
```

However, by adding a rule to produce the intermediate files:

```
b_files: $(B_FILES)
```

it's possible to make all of the intermediate files:

```
$ make b_files
```

However make deletes the .b files after it makes them because they are listed as intermediate. Is it possible to prevent make from deleting them when this specific target is used?

I think the answer would require redefining .INTERMEDIATE in the b_files rule but I am not sure if it is possible to redefine a target within a specific rule.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear; what version of Make are you using?

Comment: I am using GNU Make 3.82. Is there anything else I can clarify ?

Comment: I think I understand now, but I don't think there's any way to do this without a horrible kludge.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.PRECIOUS** or **.SECONDARY** instead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426934/why-this-makefile-removes-my-goal). If you need to do this conditionally you can use **MAKECMDGOALS** to check for special target:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),b_files)
  .SECONDARY: $(B_FILES)
endif
```

Comment: @Beta do you think this is solution (asking because you kind of specialize in makefiles)?