# gcc / make - How to define dependencies to generate and compile assembly (.s) files?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to write a makefile which generates assembly files 
(by calling gcc with the -S flag), then modifies the generated s.-files
and then compiles it. To find an approach I made a short sample 
makefile which works fine when I list the name of the .s-sourcefiles precisely (main.s, mod1.s etc.).

```
    objects = main.o mod1.o
    assembly = main.s mod1.s

    app : $(objects)
        gcc -o app $(objects)
        chmod +x app
    %.s : %.c
        gcc -S $<
    #   here some code will be called to modify 
    #   the .s file for some experimental purpose ..    
    main.o : main.s
        gcc -c main.s
    mod1.o : mod1.s
        gcc -c mod1.s
    cleanobj :
        rm app $(objects)
    cleanass :
        rm $(assembly)
    cleanall : cleanobj cleanass
```

This works as intended.
But when when I define the dependecy 
a little more generic ("%.o : %.s")
the assembly (.s) files are not generated any more:

```
    objects = main.o mod1.o
    assembly = main.s mod1.s

    app : $(objects)
        gcc -o app $(objects)
        chmod +x app
    %.s : %.c
        gcc -S $<
    #   here some code will be called to modify 
    #   the .s file for some experimental purpose ..
    %.o : %.s
        gcc -c $<
    cleanobj :
        rm app $(objects)
    cleanass :
        rm $(assembly)
    cleanall : cleanobj cleanass
```

Any explanation i.e. idea how to implement these steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark assembler files as precious:

```
.PRECIOUS: %.s
```

or just mark add following to forcedly keep all intermediate outputs:

```
.SECONDARY:
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426934/why-this-makefile-removes-my-goal).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn' t work out. This is not about files being deleted intermediately, but not being generated in the first place..
Here is the output of the first:
gcc -S main.c
gcc -c main.s
gcc -S mod1.c
gcc -c mod1.s
gcc -o app main.o mod1.o
and second makefile:
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o mod1.o mod1.c
gcc -o app main.o mod1.o
Looks like .s-files are not generated at all to me.

Comment: Ok, I was able to repro. It seems we run into the following: "rule whose prerequisites actually exist or are mentioned always takes priority over a rule with prerequisites that must be made by chaining other implicit rules" (from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html)). So your rules are overriden by implicit rules. You can disable implicit rules via make's `-r` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot yugr, the -r flag was the relevant hint!
To anyone struggeling the same behaviour:
The following makefile (compared to the above, .PRECIOUS: %.s has been added) produces the desired output (.s and .o files):

```
    objects = main.o mod1.o
    assembly = main.s mod1.s

    .PRECIOUS: %.s
    app : $(objects)
        gcc -o app $(objects)
        chmod +x app
    %.s : %.c
        gcc -S $<
    #   here some code will be called to modify 
    #   the .s file for some experimental purpose ..
    %.o : %.s
        gcc -c $<
    cleanobj :
        rm app $(objects)
    cleanass :
        rm $(assembly)
    cleanall : cleanobj cleanass
```

produces, called with

```
    make
    cc    -c -o main.o main.c
    cc    -c -o mod1.o mod1.c
    gcc -o app main.o mod1.o
    chmod +x app
```

but when called with

```
    make -r
    gcc -S main.c
    gcc -c main.s
    gcc -S mod1.c
    gcc -c mod1.s
    gcc -o app main.o mod1.o
    chmod +x app
```

ie. the demanded .s files were created, also leading to an executable 'app'.

Be aware no .o or .s file are existing in the target folders.